# Try catch in Nextflow processes

Tags: groovy, nextflow

How can I perform a try catch in nextflow?

I am currently writing a pipeline where it is possible that the bash command I am executing exits with an exitcode 1 under certain conditions. This brings my pipeline to a grinding halt. I would now like to use a try catch clause to define some alternative behavior in case this happens.

I have tried doing this in groovy fashion which does not seem to work:

```
process align_kallisto {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/kallisto", mode: 'copy', saveAs:{ filename -> "${name}_abundance.tsv" }   

    input:
    tuple val(name), file(fastq) from fq_kallisto.dump(tag: 'kallisto fq')
    file(index) from kallisto_index.collect().dump(tag: 'kallisto index')

    output:
    file("output/abundance.tsv") into kallisto_quant

    // this can throw an exit 1 status
    try {
        """
        kallisto quant -i ${index} --bias --single --fr-stranded -o output --plaintext \
          --fragment-length ${params.frag_length} --sd ${params.frag_deviation} ${fastq}
        """
    } 
    // if this happens catch and do something else
    catch (Exception e) {
        println("Exception: ${e} for $name")
        """
        // execute some alternative command
        """
    }

}
```

Any advise?

I could tell nextflow to just ignore this error and still continue, but I would rather learn how to do a proper try catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to handle errors in your process definition using a try/catch block. Rather than trying to catch *all* of the scenarios that result in an exit status 1, could you better define those conditions and handle them *before* trying to execute your process? For example, if an empty FASTQ file (or a FASTQ file with an insufficient number of reads as required by your process) was supplied as input  and this resulted in an exit status 1, a pre-processing command that filtered out those files could be useful here.

But if it's not possible to better define the condition(s) that your command produces exit status 1 or any non-zero exit status, you can ignore them like you have suggested by appending `errorStrategy 'ignore'` to your process definition. Below is an example of how you could get the 'success' and 'failed' outputs, so they can be handled appropriately:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process test {

    errorStrategy 'ignore'

    input:
    tuple val(name), path(fastq)

    output:
    tuple val(name), path("output/abundance.tsv")

    """
    if [ "${fastq.baseName}" == "empty" ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
    mkdir output
    touch output/abundance.tsv
    """
}

workflow {

    fastqs = Channel.fromFilePairs( './data/*.fastq', size: 1 )

    test(fastqs) \
        .join(fastqs, remainder: true) \
        .branch { name, abundance, fastq_tuple ->
            failed: abundance == null
                return tuple( name, *fastq_tuple )
            succeeded: true
                return tuple( name, abundance )
        } \
        .set { results }

    results.failed.view { "failed: $it" }
    results.succeeded.view { "success: $it" }
}
```

Run with:

```
mkdir data
touch data/nonempty.fastq
touch data/empty.fastq

nextflow run -ansi-log false test.nf
```

Results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `test.nf` [suspicious_newton] - revision: b883179718
[08/60a99f] Submitted process > test (1)
[42/358d60] Submitted process > test (2)
[08/60a99f] NOTE: Process `test (1)` terminated with an error exit status (1) -- Error is ignored
success: [nonempty, /home/user/working/stackoverflow/66119818/work/42/358d60bd7ac2cd8ed4dd7aef665d62/output/abundance.tsv]
failed: [empty, /home/user/working/stackoverflow/66119818/data/empty.fastq]
```